# automate actions with cron and the new api odoo

Tags: cron, odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9

I want to automate an action and here is the code that I'm using:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data noupdate="1">
        <record id="ir_cron_scheduler_demo_action" model="ir.cron">
            <field name="name">Demo scheduler</field>
            <field name="user_id" ref="base.user_root"/>
            <field name="interval_number">2</field>
            <field name="interval_type">minutes</field>
            <field name="numbercall">-1</field>
            <field eval="False" name="doall"/>
            <field eval="'note.admin'" name="model"/>
            <field eval="'process_demo_scheduler_queue'" name="function"/>
        </record>
   </data>
</openerp>
```

```py
@api.model
def process_demo_scheduler_queue(self):
    for note in self.env['note.admin']:
        if datetime.strptime(note.date, DEFAULT_SERVER_DATETIME_FORMAT).date() == datetime.now().date():
            note.write({'is_visible': True})
```

What I want to do is to set the value is_visible on True when the field note.date == current date

here is the log on server:

> 2016-05-25 01:20:17,658 3680 INFO test3 werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - -
>   [25/May/2016 01:20:17] "POST
>   /web/dataset/call_kw/note.admin/message_get_subscription_data
>   HTTP/1.1" 200 -

but it is not working!

---

SOLVED:

```
@api.model
def process_demo_scheduler_queue(self):
    notes = self.search([('date', '=', fields.Date.today())])
    notes.write({'is_visible': True})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to search for all notes in your database, and second try to use odoo's date logic:

```py
@api.model
def process_demo_scheduler_queue(self):
    for note in self.search([]):
        if note.date == openerp.fields.Date.context_today(self):
            note.is_visible = True
```

Or maybe faster:

```py
@api.model
def process_demo_scheduler_queue(self):
    notes = self.search([('date', '=', openerp.fields.Date.context_today(self))])
    notes.write({'is_visible': True})
```

Comment: I loved the faster way, Tank you T_T

Answer (score 2):

You have to write like below code,

```
@api.model
def process_demo_scheduler_queue(self):
    for note in self.env['note.admin'].search([]):
        if datetime.strptime(note.date, DEFAULT_SERVER_DATETIME_FORMAT).date() == datetime.now().date():
            note.write({'is_visible': True})
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, i forgot the ".search([])"